# Buen dia, tengo una duda sobre cómo implementar una función con un EventTarget en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Este es mi código:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click').

function () {
    // body...

    var setBar; 
    setBar = document.getElementById('setBar');
    setBar = setBar.value;
    setBar = parseInt(setBar);

    var setBar1; 
    setBar1 = document.getElementById('setBar1');
    setBar1 = setBar1.value;
    setBar1 = parseInt(setBar1);

    console.log(setBar);
    console.log(setBar1);
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda?

Comment: Como puedo usar el addEventListener('click'). y ponerla en una funcion

Comment: [Está explicado en la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Revisa las explicaciones y los ejemplos y si no entiendes algo pregunta sobre aquello que no entiendas.

Comment: Ah OK, muchas gracias. Ya pude entender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer el evento addEventListener no ibas mal encaminado, solo te faltó agregarle la función. Porque tal y como tu lo pusiste si, funciona, el js detecta el click en X sitio, pero nada más.

Te pongo como ejemplo cómo hacer las funciones llamadas por eventos (explicación en el código comentado):

```js
document.body.innerHTML = `<input type="text" name="uno">
    <input type="text" name="dos">`;//esto es para crear mediante strict strings el html

    let inp_1 = document.querySelector('input[name=uno]');//iniciamos la variable inp_1 y le damos como valor el input de nombre uno
    console.log(inp_1);//comprobamos que funciona correctamente, despues se puede borrar esta linea
    let inp_2 = document.querySelector('input[name=dos]');//lo mismo con el input dos
    console.log(inp_2);


    inp_1.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{//agregamos a inp_1 el evento de escucha 'click', que llama a la función anónima
        //la cual paso e como parámetro
        console.log(e.target.value);//y devolvemos el valor del e.target
    });


    inp_2.addEventListener('keyup',(e)=>{//en este evento iniciamos con un keyup, es decir, cada vez que se pulsa la tecla

        //e representaría la tecla, la cual podrías sacar con e.key
        console.log(e.key);
        //pero imprimimos por consola el valor del input, ya que el parámetro no nos haría falta
        console.log(inp_2.value);
        //esto es funcionalidad de los kelogger al fin y al cabo, solo que super simplificado
    });
```

Comment: Ah okay, muchas gracias, ahora ya entendi como

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos